# Changing Ionic Cordova TabRoot Dynamically during runtime

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created an Ionic Tabs Application.

**Tabs.html:**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="md-home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="md-information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="My Account" tabIcon="md-log-in"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

and **Tabs.ts**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = LoginPage;

  constructor()
  {}

}
```

What I want to do is once I'm on tab3Root (LoginPage) and I login, I want to change it to the LoggedinPage.
Maintaining the other tabs functioning and normal.

Is that possible? If yes how please?

Thank you

Added Info: check/edit this link it contains my code as example
stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yff2sx

Comment: Yes you can do like create tabs from array from ts. When user logged in you have to update tabs from login page

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I tried setting tab3Root = LoggedinPage after logging in but that did not have effect at all if that's what you mean... I think it doesnt work because the root was already set on initialization... so changing tab3Root after initialization is useless. any idea on how to do it? thank you!

Comment: Your problem is how to call `setRoot` in a provider, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call the other page from that tab using setRoot method. call the below method from Login page.

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.loggedInPage);
```

[Please refer this working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tab-issue)

I have assumed home.ts as log In page and called the loggedIn page from home page. After clicking **go to Logged In page** button in home page, Logged In page content will replace the home page content.

Comment: Thanks!! That does actually work and I have tried it already, the problem is I'm doing the "login" functionalities in an Injectable class. therefor I can not use the above method. Is there a way to call a function in the LogIn Page from the Injectable Class so it performs this task? I am not able to call a function from outside my Injectable class.

Comment: Removed the Injectable and implemented the function in the component instead!

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the provider as injectable class I guess. Use injectable class only for business validation and HTTP requests. Page construction and page navigation should happen on component class.. please edit your question with all the files and expectations

Comment: ah i see! ok done thanks for the tip! I have moved them to the local ,ts file (component). but without the Injectable i am now unable to verify whether the user is signed in or not using (auth.user | async) this check is happening in the HomePage (show as guest if not) while actual user login functionality are in the LogIn Page. with the Injectable i used to be able to do that. ok will do! I'll use https://stackblitz.com

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yff2sx here is my example. As you can see its checking if user is authethicated in the constructor of the LoginPage. and in order for the homepage to know if he is authenticated, it needs to check the loginpage function. thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah every time when the user launches the App it will come to login component and in constructor you will check if the user is authenticated already. if he's authenticated already just use setRoot to navigate the user to other page in same tab. If you are worried that login page will display for sometime before the authentication, put some condition to hide the page till authentication block gets complete or display some loading icon till authentication gets complete.

Answer (score 2):

According to prithivi Raj answer you will be able to navigate to that page but you can not highlight the tabs icon.

inOrder to do that you have you do some thing like this

```
 this.navCtrl.parrent.select(0);
```

Consider you are in tab3 and after you login you want to navigate to tab1/tab2 just mention the index in the above code parameter like `this.navCtrl.parrent.select(0);` / `this.navCtrl.parrent.select(1)`;. it will lead you to that tab if you use `this.navCtrl.setRoot("this. loggedInPage"); it will not highlight the tabs which will lead the user confusion in which tab he is active now.